# Having trouble install a package from GitHub

Tags: r

I am new to R, but I have spent 3-4 hours trying to install the "baseballr" package from GitHub without any luck. I've tried several versions of R, but always get a error that looks something like this. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

````
#install.packages("devtools") > devtools::install_github("BillPetti/baseballr")
Downloading GitHub repo BillPetti/baseballr@HEAD
**
Skipping 3 packages not available: latticeExtra, RCurl, XML
Installing 29 packages: bit, checkmate, viridis, htmlTable, data.table, gridExtra, acepack, latticeExtra, Formula, plyr, RCurl, XML, TTR, zoo, xts, bit64, Hmisc, hexbin, XML2R, snakecase, igraph, quantmod, rlist, vroom, pbapply, reldist, pitchRx, janitor, highcharter
Error: Failed to install 'baseballr' from GitHub:
  (converted from warning) packages ‘latticeExtra’, ‘RCurl’, ‘XML’ are not available (for R version 3.3.3)
** ```
````

Comment: Your R version is a bit old.  The current version is `R 4.0.2`

Comment: Have you tried `install.packages(c("latticeExtra","RCurl","XML"), type="source")`? It will take a moment to compile them all, but perhaps it'll let you get past the fact that you're on a version of R [released in March 2017](https://cloud.r-project.org/src/base/R-3/).

Comment: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RCurl/index.html depends on >=R3.4.0, perhaps other packages too. So upgrade R if you can